# Вместо скачивания в csv данные выводится на страницу текстом

Tags: php, slim

Всем привет. Есть "полурабочий" вариант кода, который по задумке должен скачивать данные, полученные из БД файлом .csv. Полурабочий он, собственно, потому, что если запрос из БД отдает небольшой объем данных, то файл скачивает, но если из БД возвращается более 25-30 строк, то все эти данные выводятся текстом на страницу, вместо того, чтобы отдать это файлом.
Сама функция выглядит так:

```
public function getReport( Request $request, Response $response ): Response
{
  $form = $request->getParsedBody();

  $get_report = $this->database->getConnection()->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE date between :after AND :before' );
  $get_report->execute([
    'after' => $form['date-after'],
    'before' =>  $form['date-before']
  ]);

  $stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');

  while($row = $get_report->fetch()) {
      fputcsv($stream, $row, ";");
  };

  return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv')
    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv";');
}
```

сам никак осилить не могу, пришел к вам за помощью :{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что вы пытаетесь записать данные в поток `php://output` прямо в функции. Это может привести к тому, что данные будут отправлены до того, как будут установлены заголовки ответа, что приведет к неправильной обработке браузером.

Вместо этого, вы можете использовать временный поток, который затем можно передать в ответ. Вот как это может выглядеть:

```php
public function getReport( Request $request, Response $response ): Response
{
  $form = $request->getParsedBody();

  $get_report = $this->database->getConnection()->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM cafe WHERE date between :after AND :before' );
  $get_report->execute([
    'after' => $form['date-after'],
    'before' =>  $form['date-before']
  ]);

  // Создаем временный поток
  $stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

  while($row = $get_report->fetch()) {
      fputcsv($stream, $row, ";");
  };

  // Перемещаем указатель обратно в начало потока
  rewind($stream);

  // Получаем содержимое потока
  $csv = stream_get_contents($stream);

  // Закрываем поток
  fclose($stream);

  // Создаем поток для ответа
  $body = $response->getBody();
  $body->write($csv);

  return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv')
    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv";')
    ->withBody($body);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде сработало, файл скачивается.